# Using node library on isomorphic React / Redux / Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server

I am working on an isomorphic react project and am attempting to use the Stripe node SDK (vs their REST API) within a Redux module. When Webpack builds the project I get the error: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process'`. I know this is a node only module, so I cannot use it on the browser (I only want Stripe API calls to originate on the server-side), I just don't know how to ensure that the Stripe node_module is not packaged in to the browser app.js file.

While I am importing the stripe module in the redux module, on the JSX side, I am only importing the IStripe interface from the stripe.model and the getPlansList dispatcher from my stripe redux module.

So my question is how does one use node-only modules within an isomorphic React project? Do I need to run a separate server-only node process that handles my Stripe calls? Or is it possible to contain this functionality within my isomorphic app?

Thanks!

Comment: Just doing some research. It seems like it would be a good idea to implement an API proxy that both the server and client can use. That way I can protect my private API credentials on the server side. Something like this: https://github.com/topheman/topheman-apis-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/139), you should not run `stripe-node` in browser.

You can setup `alias` in webpack config:

```
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'stripe': './src/stripe-browser'
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need to use Stripe in browser, you can just create an empty file `stripe-browser` as a stub for API.

If you are going to use API in browser, you have to create an adapter to [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) client-side library.

Comment: I don't wish to use any third-party API's from the browser. I only want to make these calls from the server-side. From what I have read and seen in some isomorphic react boilerplate templates, there is an API proxy that it utilized. But I am curious what making an empty stripe-browser stub does. Will that work on the server-side and not on the browser side?

Comment: As far as you put `alias` in `webpack` config, it affects only webpack build. So you can run your code with `node` it would work as expected.